# Use preg_match to grab value from URL

Tags: php, url, preg-match

I have a url something like:

www.yourname.mysite.com/templates/diversity/index.php

I need to grab that string, "diversity", and match it against a db value. I've never used anything like preg_match in php, how can I grab that string?

Comment: Can you expand on what makes 'diversity' the target? Is it the directory preceding the file? Is it the second directory in the path?

Comment: diversity is the second directory in the path

Comment: what do you mean with grab? check if the string has /diversity/ in it?

Comment: not really to check if it the url has /diversity/ in it - but to grab whatever is in that directory position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $ex = explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    echo $ex[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer's but this was the easiest and quickest to implement - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a regular expression, you can use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for that:

```
$url = 'www.yourname.mysite.com/templates/diversity/index.php';

$parts = parse_url($url);
$paths = explode('/', $parts['path']);
// "diversity" is in $paths[1]
```

For completeness' sake, here's the regular expression:

```
preg_match('=^[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/=', $url, $matches);
// "diversity" is in $matches[1]
```

Comment: thx - but what is the $url value? Can i dynamically pull the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can just explode that string and get the third value of the resulting array:

```
$parts = explode("/", "www.yourname.mysite.com/templates/diversity/index.php");
echo $parts[2]; // diversity
```

Comment: How do I get the url if it is dynamic?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be his case, but he can just str_replace that http:// before exploding with "/"